# Microsoft visual studio 2010 has encountered an error needs to close

Tags: visual-studio-2010, mfc

i want to create a simple MFC test application . after selection of  dialogue based "MFC application" my visual studio 2010 closes and gives this error "Microsoft visual studio has encountered an error and needs to stop" and my VS2010 environment restarts. Any help will be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Suggestion: Don't install malware. Visual Studio works, on millions of devices. Unless your system is broken. Fix your system.

Comment: Nature's way of telling you to reinstall windows.

Comment: @IInspectable could you explain your answer please. how can i do it now

Comment: @zeromus i already uninstall and install my VS2010. but it did not work.

Comment: I didn't say reinstall VS2010. Workaround: create template MFC project on another system, save it forever, and copy it every time you need to create a new MFC project.

Comment: Make sure to patch up to SP1. It does make a difference. I've rarely seen the error and I work with 2010 every day.